# Send a message to specific people including sender using socket.io in nodejs

Tags: node.js, socket.io

How to send a message to particular client including sender..

The following is the code i used to send a message to particular client.

```
socket.on('chat message', function(msg){
io.to(socket.id).emit('chat message', msg);
});
```

Ofcourse its working But it just sending to the client(reciever) only.But i want to send a message to particular client(reciever) including sender also.

Is anything need to add in that code.?? suggestions are welcome.!!

Thanks,

Comment: You have to handle it from your server end. With one request from app you will be able to send message to both end, have to do some effort at server side.

Comment: @dev, thanks for suggestion .Can u give me some example or any web link related to this topic.I searched so many sites but i din't get answer for it till now.!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 ways to achieve same from server end

1) Emit event to both user separately
2) Broadcast event to array of user(In your case senderId, reciverId)

Here i am enclosing broadcast function considering you are already aware with emit.

```
client.broadcast.to(arrayOfIds).emit('eventName', {
                data: "somedata"
            });
```

Here,
arrayOfIds : Array of Id of Recivers, i.e.(Id Of sender and Id Of receiver)

This function with send event to both user, including sender him self.

Comment: Hi @Dev_Tandel, it seems like client.broadcast.to(array) not work. For example, I run with client.broadcast.to([senderId, receiverId]).emit(....), it does not send to sender and receiver at all. Also try io.sockets.to([senderId, receiverId]).emit(....), this not work too

Comment: @QuocVanTang - it's been long since the answer, I am not working on socket recently. I will update the answer with the new version when I will work. You can too update the answer if you have found the solution in recent version.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Currently, for sending to sender and receiver, I make 2 separated socket emit for this purpose: 1 for sender, 1 for the broadcast. But still dont know is there any way to do it with only 1 line of code